# Creating multiple modals using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm in the middle of building a multiple modal for my website that I'm working on. I've managed to start with something and currently I'm stuck in trying to make modals trigger separately from one another. It is basically how bootstrap does it by appending a data-attribute I believe. I could have just use bootstrap to solve my problem but I would like to avoid all the code bloat and just built it myself.

Here a sample code that I have been working on. I've managed to make the looping but it seems to open the wrong modal.

```js
    $('.modal-container').insertAfter('.layout-container');

    $('.modal-container').each(function(i) {
        $(this).attr('id', "modal" + (i + 1));

        modal_container_id = $(this).attr('data-modal', "modal" + (i + 1));
    });

    $('.modal-item .modal-btn').each(function(i) {

        var modal_id = $(this).attr('id', "modal" + (i + 1));

        $(modal_id).on('click', function() {
            $(modal_container_id).addClass('show-modal');
            $('body').addClass('lock-scroll');
        });
    })


    //Close Modal
 $('.modal-container .close-modal').on('click', function() {
     $('.modal-container').removeClass('show-modal');
     $('body').removeClass('lock-scroll');
 })
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block; }

body {
  line-height: 1; }

ol, ul {
  list-style: none; }

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none; }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none; }

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0; }

.layout-container {
  position: relative; }

.modal-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in; }
  .modal-container.show-modal {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in; }
  .modal-container .modal-body {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #fff; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="layout-container">
    <div class="modal-item">
        <button class="modal-btn">Modal One Trigger</button>

        <div class="modal-container">
            <button class="close-modal">Close Modal</button>
            Modal One
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="modal-item">
        <button class="modal-btn">Modal Two Trigger</button>

        <div class="modal-container">
            <button class="close-modal">Close Modal</button>
            Modal Two
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: We need more of your HTML - we can't see how you have coded your Modals

Comment: you have several errors here: first, you give `modal1` / `modal2` as id to both the opening buttons and the modal div, and every id should be unique, change one of the prefix. Second, you don't select the good element in the click function, but you reuse a previous var `$(modal_container_id)`. Use a selector based on the button id instead

Comment: When you intent to use id selector prefix `#` i.e. `$('#' + modal_id)`, However its better to use to DOM traversal method to target the desired element

Comment: @Satpal basically the way I did is if the `ID` on the button matches the `ID` on the `.modal-container` class it will trigger and show the modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the below changes to your code, it will work fine.

**Changes made:**

1. I have commented out the line `$(this).attr('id', "modal" + (i + 1))` as it will create duplicate `id` for `modal-container`.
2. Change `$(modal_container_id).addClass('show-modal');` to `$("[data-modal='" + $(this).attr("id") + "']").addClass('show-modal');` as `modal_container_id` refers to `modal2` because of previous loop.

```js
$('.modal-container').insertAfter('.layout-container');

$('.modal-container').each(function (i) {
 modal_container_id = $(this).attr('data-modal', "modal" + (i + 1));
});

$('.modal-item .modal-btn').each(function (i) {
 var modal_id = $(this).attr('id', "modal" + (i + 1));
 $(modal_id).on('click', function () {
  $("[data-modal='" + $(this).attr("id") + "']").addClass('show-modal');
  $('body').addClass('lock-scroll');
 });
})

//Close Modal
$('.modal-container .close-modal').on('click', function () {
 $('.modal-container').removeClass('show-modal');
 $('body').removeClass('lock-scroll');
})
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
v2.0 | 20110126
License: none (public domain)
*/

 html,
 body,
 div,
 span,
 applet,
 object,
 iframe,
 h1,
 h2,
 h3,
 h4,
 h5,
 h6,
 p,
 blockquote,
 pre,
 a,
 abbr,
 acronym,
 address,
 big,
 cite,
 code,
 del,
 dfn,
 em,
 img,
 ins,
 kbd,
 q,
 s,
 samp,
 small,
 strike,
 strong,
 sub,
 sup,
 tt,
 var,
 b,
 u,
 i,
 center,
 dl,
 dt,
 dd,
 ol,
 ul,
 li,
 fieldset,
 form,
 label,
 legend,
 table,
 caption,
 tbody,
 tfoot,
 thead,
 tr,
 th,
 td,
 article,
 aside,
 canvas,
 details,
 embed,
 figure,
 figcaption,
 footer,
 header,
 hgroup,
 menu,
 nav,
 output,
 ruby,
 section,
 summary,
 time,
 mark,
 audio,
 video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
 }

 /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

 article,
 aside,
 details,
 figcaption,
 figure,
 footer,
 header,
 hgroup,
 menu,
 nav,
 section {
  display: block;
 }

 body {
  line-height: 1;
 }

 ol,
 ul {
  list-style: none;
 }

 blockquote,
 q {
  quotes: none;
 }

 blockquote:before,
 blockquote:after,
 q:before,
 q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
 }

 table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
 }

 .layout-container {
  position: relative;
 }

 .modal-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
 }

 .modal-container.show-modal {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
 }

 .modal-container .modal-body {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
 }

 /*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="layout-container">
 <div class="modal-item">
  <button class="modal-btn">Modal One Trigger</button>

  <div class="modal-container">
   <button class="close-modal">Close Modal</button>
   Modal One
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="modal-item">
  <button class="modal-btn">Modal Two Trigger</button>

  <div class="modal-container">
   <button class="close-modal">Close Modal</button>
   Modal Two
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question. You want to show the respective modal container on button click events. I have simplified the code. Hope it works.

```js
        $('.modal-btn').on('click', function() {
            $(this).next('.modal-container').addClass('show-modal');
            $('body').addClass('lock-scroll');
        });


    //Close Modal
 $('.modal-container .close-modal').on('click', function() {
     $('.modal-container').removeClass('show-modal');
     $('body').removeClass('lock-scroll');
 })
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block; }

body {
  line-height: 1; }

ol, ul {
  list-style: none; }

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none; }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none; }

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0; }

.layout-container {
  position: relative; }

.modal-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in; }
  .modal-container.show-modal {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in; }
  .modal-container .modal-body {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #fff; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="layout-container">
    <div class="modal-item">
        <button class="modal-btn">Modal One Trigger</button>

        <div class="modal-container">
            <button class="close-modal">Close Modal</button>
            Modal One
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="modal-item">
        <button class="modal-btn">Modal Two Trigger</button>

        <div class="modal-container">
            <button class="close-modal">Close Modal</button>
            Modal Two
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hold on what if the `.modal-container` is outside the `.layout-container` class hence `$('.modal-container').insertAfter('.layout-container');` it needs to be outside

Comment: Here .modal-container and .modal-btn both are under same parent. If .modal-container is outside the .layout-container you can use jQuery parent() method to find closest .modal-container.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [Jquery UI](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) to create modals.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $( ".dialog" ).dialog({
   autoOpen: false
  });
  
  $("#modal1Btn").click(function(){
   $( "#dialog1" ).dialog("open" );
  });
  
  $("#modal2Btn").click(function(){
   $( "#dialog2" ).dialog("open" );
  })
 })
```

```html
  <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 
 <button id="modal1Btn" class="modal-btn">Modal One Trigger</button>
 <button id="modal2Btn" class="modal-btn">Modal Two Trigger</button>
 
<div class="dialog" id="dialog1" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Dailog 1</p>
</div>

<div class="dialog" id="dialog2" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Dailog 2</p>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've edited your js mantaining the html structure. You only have to elaborate ids before moving the modal outside the container ;)

```js
$('.modal-item').each(function(idx) {
  var $modal = $(this).find('.modal-container'),
    $button = $(this).find('.modal-btn');
  $button.data('modal', '#modal-' + idx);
  $modal.attr('id', 'modal-' + idx);
  $modal.insertAfter('.layout-container');
});

$('.layout-container').on('click', '.modal-btn', function() {
  $($(this).data('modal')).addClass('show-modal');
  $('body').addClass('lock-scroll');
});

//Close Modal
$('.modal-container .close-modal').on('click', function() {
  $('.modal-container').removeClass('show-modal');
  $('body').removeClass('lock-scroll');
})
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block; }

body {
  line-height: 1; }

ol, ul {
  list-style: none; }

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none; }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none; }

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0; }

.layout-container {
  position: relative; }

.modal-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in; }
  .modal-container.show-modal {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in; }
  .modal-container .modal-body {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #fff; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="layout-container">
    <div class="modal-item">
        <button class="modal-btn">Modal One Trigger</button>

        <div class="modal-container">
            <button class="close-modal">Close Modal</button>
            Modal One
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="modal-item">
        <button class="modal-btn">Modal Two Trigger</button>

        <div class="modal-container">
            <button class="close-modal">Close Modal</button>
            Modal Two
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```